# Canvas Greek google fonts not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, fonts

I assume that this is a bug but if any of you know any work around please let me know.

First of all, the fonts are loaded 101%.

1. I load Google fonts synchronously
2. I check with interval to make sure that the font is loaded.
3. I convert a string into an image (with the below function) by using canvas with success (when
   I use English characters)
4. After rendering a couple English characters I try to render a Greek
   word but canvas fall backs to browsers default font.
5. Firefox doesn't have any issue at all, it works great. The issue is
   with Chrome.

Bellow is the function that creates a ribbon-label background image on the top left corner from a given string (PS: this function return imageData that are being merged with other imageData later on):

```
ImageProcessor.prototype.createLabelImageData = function ( str, size, font, color, backgroundColor, shadowColor, shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY, shadowBlur, width, height ) {

    this.canvas.width = width || this.settings.width;
    this.canvas.height = height || this.settings.height;
    this.ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height );

    this.ctx.font = "Bold " + ( size || 64 ) + "px " + ( font || "Arial" );
    this.ctx.textAlign = "center";
    this.ctx.textBaseline = "middle";

    var labelHeight = ( size || 64 ) + ( ( size || 64 ) / 4 );
    var labelTop = this.canvas.height / 2 - labelHeight / 2;
    var labelWidth = this.canvas.width;

    var strLen = this.ctx.measureText( str + "    " ).width;
    var side = Math.sqrt( ( strLen * strLen ) / 2 );
    var distance = Math.sqrt( ( side * side ) - ( ( strLen / 2 ) * ( strLen / 2 ) ) );

    this.ctx.save();
    this.ctx.rotate( -Math.PI / 4 );
    this.ctx.translate( -this.canvas.width / 2, -this.canvas.height / 2 + distance );

    this.ctx.fillStyle = ( backgroundColor || '#f00' );
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo( 0, labelTop );
    this.ctx.lineTo( labelWidth, labelTop );
    this.ctx.lineTo( labelWidth, labelTop + labelHeight );
    this.ctx.lineTo( 0, labelTop + labelHeight );
    this.ctx.closePath();
    this.ctx.fill();

    if ( shadowColor ) {

        this.ctx.shadowColor = shadowColor;
        this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = ( shadowOffsetX || 0 );
        this.ctx.shadowOffsetY = ( shadowOffsetY || 0 );
        this.ctx.shadowBlur = ( shadowBlur || size || 64 );

    }

    this.ctx.fillStyle = ( color || "#fff" );
    this.ctx.fillText( str, this.canvas.width / 2, this.canvas.height / 2 );
    this.ctx.restore();

    var imageData = this.ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height );

    this.canvas.width = this.settings.width;
    this.canvas.height = this.settings.height;

    return imageData;

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some testing, trial and error and many many hours of reading...

I found out that it doesn't matter if the font has been downloaded when you want to use it in canvas. What worked for me before anything else and any check was to create n*2 div elements (n the number of fonts loaded) and position them outside of the view-port. n*2 because in some I added `font-weight:bold`.

Bottom line is that the exact font you wish to use in canvas must be:

1. Preloaded
2. Create a dummy dom element with innerHTML text of all language
   variations (latin & greek in my case).

Keep in mid that you have to create extra elements for the bold variation of the font.

Here is the code that I'm currently using to preload fonts and make sure they are available in canvas.

```
Vise.prototype.initializeFonts = function ( settings, globalCallback ) {



    var that = this; // reference to parent class



    /********************************************
     ********************************************
     **
     **
     **     Default settings
     **
     **
     ********************************************
     ********************************************/



    var defaults = {
        interval: 100,
        timeout: 10000,
        families: [
            'Open+Sans+Condensed:300,300italic,700:latin,greek',
            'Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800:latin,greek',
            'Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300:latin,greek',
            'Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic:latin,greek'
        ]
    };

    // initialization

    this.fonts = new Fonts( $.extend( true, defaults, settings ) );
    this.fonts.onload = globalCallback;
    this.fonts.load();

};



/********************************************
 ********************************************
 **
 **
 **     Fonts class
 **
 **
 ********************************************
 ********************************************/



function Fonts( settings ) {

    this.settings = settings;
    this.success = [];
    this.fail = [];
    this.interval = null;
    this.elapsedTime = this.settings.interval;
    this.fontDetective = new Detector();

}

Fonts.prototype.load = function () {

    WebFont.load( {
        google: {
            families: this.settings.families
        }
    } );

    for ( var i in this.settings.families ) {

        var el, elBold;
        var familyStr = this.settings.families[ i ];
        var family = familyStr.split( ':' )[ 0 ].replace( /[+]/gi, ' ' );

        el = document.createElement( "div" );
        el.innerHTML = "Font loader  Φόρτωμα γραμματοσειράς";
        el.style.fontFamily = family;
        el.style.color = "#f00";
        el.style.position = "fixed";
        el.style.zIndex = 9999;
        el.style.left = "9999px";
        document.body.appendChild( el );

        elBold = document.createElement( "div" );
        elBold.innerHTML = "Font loader  Φόρτωμα γραμματοσειράς";
        elBold.style.fontFamily = family;
        elBold.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        elBold.style.color = "#f00";
        elBold.style.position = "fixed";
        elBold.style.zIndex = 9999;
        elBold.style.left = "9999px";
        document.body.appendChild( elBold );

    }

    this.interval = setInterval( this.areLoaded.bind( this ), this.settings.interval );

};

Fonts.prototype.areLoaded = function () {

    for ( var i in this.settings.families ) {

        var familyStr = this.settings.families[ i ];
        var family = familyStr.split( ':' )[ 0 ].replace( /[+]/gi, ' ' );
        var successIdx, failIdx;

        if ( this.fontDetective.detect( family ) ) {

            successIdx = this.success.indexOf( family );
            failIdx = this.fail.indexOf( family );

            if ( successIdx === -1 ) {
                this.success.push( family );
                console.log( "[" + family + "] was successfully loaded." );
            }

            if ( failIdx > -1 ) {
                this.fail.splice( failIdx, 1 );
            }

        } else {

            successIdx = this.success.indexOf( family );
            failIdx = this.fail.indexOf( family );

            if ( successIdx > -1 ) {
                this.success.splice( successIdx, 1 );
            }

            if ( failIdx === -1 ) {
                this.fail.push( family );
            }

        }

    }

    if ( this.elapsedTime >= this.settings.timeout ) {

        clearInterval( this.interval );

        var err = new Error( "Unable to load fonts: " + this.fail.toString() );

        this.onload( err, null );

        return;
    }

    if ( this.success.length === this.settings.families.length ) {

        clearInterval( this.interval );

        this.onload( null, null );

        return;
    }

    this.elapsedTime += this.settings.interval;

};
```

This is what worked for me in case someone else has the same issue on chrome.

PS: Take a look at [fontdetect.js](http://www.lalit.org/lab/javascript-css-font-detect/) which I use in my code.